# returning all “Enabled” variations in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What’s the correct syntax to return all variations of a variable product with “Enabled” checked on the WooCommerce front end?

It looks like “Enabled” is represented by the ‘status’ key with a value of “publish” in the WC_Product_Variation Object.

This returns all variations, including variations with ‘status’ of ‘publish’ and ‘private’:

```
$args = array('status' => 'publish');
$variations = $product->get_children($args);
```

This returns no variations:

```
$args = array(
    'parent' => $product_id,
    'status' => 'publish',
);
$variations = wc_get_products( $args );
```

These return subsets of variations with a ‘status’ of ‘publish’ and in some scenarios exclude some variations with ‘stock_quantity’ > 0:

```
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
$variations = $product->get_visible_children();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
$args = array(
        'status' => 'publish',
        'type' => 'variation',
        'parent' => $product_id, //This is the ID of the parent variable product
    );
    
    $variations = wc_get_products($args);
```

Comment: Thanks!  With the additional parameter 'type' => 'variation', wc_get_products returns all "Enabled" variations.  It's counter intuitive that adding a restriction would increase the count, but it works.  I'd like to understand what the default order is in which the variations are returned.  It looks random to me.  Adding 'orderby' => 'id' generated the array of variations I was looking for.